# Obtener información de un HTTP response para manejarla con ajax | Sección de comentarios con Django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, http

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web con **django**, en donde tengo una **sección de comentarios**. Estoy intentado:

1. Que al publicar el comentario se haga un POST request al view de esa página
2. Crear un nuevo comentario con mi modelo de comentarios y guardarlo
3. Pre renderizar una página html que solo contiene los comentarios
4. Mandar un http response que contenga el html de los comentarios
5. Del lado del cliente, con javascript remplazar la sección de comentarios con el nuevo html que obtengo (los comentarios actualizados)

Todo esto con el motivo de que la página no haga refresh, cada vez que hago un comentario.

**(Explico el error al final)**

Esto es lo que llevo hasta el momento

En mi views.py esta es la vista que renderiza mi pagina que tiene una sección de comentarios.
No estoy devolviendo el renderizado de los comentarios todavía. Porque estoy teniendo problemas que explicaré más adelante.

```
def make_bid(request, pk):
    listing = Listing.objects.get(id = pk)
    comments = listing.comments.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            comment = Comment(
                user = request.user,
                comment= request.POST['comment'],
                date = datetime.datetime.now().date(),
                listing = listing)
            comment.save()
            context = {'comments': listing.comments.all()}
            rendered = render_to_string("auctions/comments.html", context)
            return HttpResponse("object")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("user is not even authenticated")
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/make-bid.html", {
            'article' : listing,
            'comments': comments
        })
```

La sección de comentarios de la página con html

```
    <aside class="comment__section">
        <h3>Comments</h3>
        <form action="{% url 'make-bid' article.id %}" method="post" id="form-comment">
            {% csrf_token%}
            <textarea id="textbox" class="field form__field--block" value="" name="comment" placeholder="What do you think about this listing?"></textarea>
            <input class="button button__primary" type="submit" value="Publish">
        </form>
        <section class="comment__container">
        </section>
    </aside>
```

Ajax para mandar el POST request y recibir el http response
Esto lo copié de otra página de stackoverflow. Preferiría hacerlo sin jquery, lo intenté con javascript y no obtenía el resultado esperado. Así que para asegurarme lo hice con jquery y de igual forma no obtengo el resultado que quiero

```
    $("#from-comment").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data); // show response from the php script.
            console.log('Submission was successful.');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("no response")
        }
        });

    });
```

Así se ve la sección de comentarios de mi página
[image: Como se ve mi sección de comentarios en el navegador]

Ahora aquí viene **el problema**
Al enviar el comentario el http response me devuelve el mensaje como html en toda la pantalla. Yo quiero obtener ese mensaje y hacer algo con él con javascript. No quiero que se vea

Ya se que pueden haber otras cositas mal en el código pero por ahora lo que necesito es que el http response no haga esto:
[image: Resultado al cargar el http response]

Ya he intentado mandar un JsonResponse y es lo mismo. Me devuelve lo que escribir en HttpResponse("el json pero bien hecho") como un texto en toda la página

Comment: no se por que quieres traer todo un HTML, lo único que necesitas es traer los datos, recorrerlos y mostrarlos.

Comment: @Christian Hola Gracias por tu comentario. Como podría traer los datos? El problema es que el HTTP response siempre me está devolviendo lo que le pase de esa forma tipo html. Y lo que quiero es controlar la respuesta con ajax.  Hay otra forma de traer los datos? O como arreglo el HTTP response?

Comment: Como estas trayendo los datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo resolvi! El problema era yo. Hice unos errores muy bobos en el javascript

Aqui esta el jquery. No me di cuenta que jquery no estaba cargando y tenía un typo

```
<script src="{%static 'auctions/scripts/jquery-3.6.0.js' %}"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){


        $("#form-comment").submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#comments").html(data);
                
                $("#textbox").val('')
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("no response")
            }
            });
        });
        })
</script>
```

Asi quedo el views.py

```
def make_bid(request, pk):
    listing = Listing.objects.get(id = pk)
    context = {'comments': listing.comments.all()}
    rendered = render_to_string("auctions/comments.html", context)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            comment = Comment(
                user = request.user,
                comment= request.POST['comment'],
                date = datetime.datetime.now().date(),
                listing = listing)
            comment.save()
            context = {'comments': listing.comments.all()}
            rendered = render_to_string("auctions/comments.html", context)
            return HttpResponse(rendered)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("user is not even authenticated")
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/make-bid.html", {
            'article' : listing,
            'comments': rendered
        })
```

Y así modifique el HTML de la sección de comentarios

```
    <aside class="comment__section" >
        <h3>Comments</h3>
        <form method="post" id="form-comment">
            {% csrf_token%}
            <textarea id="textbox" class="field form__field--block" value="" name="comment" placeholder="What do you think about this listing?"></textarea>
            <input class="button button__primary" type="submit" value="Publish">
        </form>
        <section class="comment__container" id="comments">
            {{comments}}
        </section>
    </aside>
```